# Is C# truly viable for a modern web-socket server?

Tags: c#, websocket

I need to develop a fairly scalable socket server for an HTML5 / Mobile based turn-based type game.

Time is a real factor in this as I need to prototype out something in 3 months. I have extensive (years) of experience in C# and zero experience in Node or Erlang which I've singled out as the perfect languages for this project. Unfortunately, both of those languages will have a lot of learning curve associated with them and things such as code quality, unit tests, maintainability I will have no experience with so I imagine the code will be of a poor quality.

How bad of a decision will it be to choose to go with C# for this project to save development time as I will have a lot more headaches with scalability and things down the line.

Is C# seriously considered viable for a modern web-app socket server?

Comment: Have you considered using SingalR ? http://goo.gl/3DcT6

Comment: Node isn't a language (and it's not particularly scalable either). But what are your needs? Why do you think that a modern server cannot be written in C#?

Comment: Yeah, I have considered using SignalR and/or Alchemy server on-top of C#.

Comment: Sure.  But you are certainly better off not to try to reinvent that wheel.  Web servers have been written and endlessly optimized for the past 20 years, not something you can catch up with in a month or less.  Surely there's already one available on your platform.

Comment: Well, the SE web-socket server drives the 60k+ concurrent connections (realtime page updates etc) that we get here at SE... and barely registers (CPU) in task-manager. Does that count?

Comment: Yes, using HttpListener/OWIN I've managed to get 982Mbps outbound via .NET Websockets via SSL in C# on a single Azure VM - so more than capable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A person can write bad code on any platform. Or good code. Yes you can write a very good low impact highly-scalable server in c#. But if this is the first such you've written (regardless of platform), chances are you'll fail to write it efficiently, and then conclude it was the platform's fault.

As an example, the web-socket server that drives instant updates here on SO/SE is written in c#, handles 60k+ connections, and barely registers as any CPU. But it was *designed* for that, with fully async network access, buffer-recycling, dedicated worker threads, etc.

Actually, if you are specifically looking for web-socket code, then .NET 4.5 on Windows 8 will include inbuilt web-socket support via HTTP.SYS (with managed wrappers, obviously), but it can be done manually. I could *possibly* even share the library we wrote to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Short: **Yes**.

Long: c# is statically typed, and it's actually compiled to native code (on Windows) and the speed is simply awesome in my experience. Consider it like C++ with garbage collector :-) Value types + true generics make things much faster than e.g. Java, and I would consider it good enough, too.

Note that you should not get scared by [benchmarks game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/), it uses Mono.

And if you  would really get into trouble, **you can** do **unsafe** operations if you really need them. So no need to worry for the future.